# Como eu poderia fazer um app que funcione em background com python e kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, notificação

Eu estou tentando fazer um app em kivy que pegue infomações de um banco de dados em segundo plano, e quando ocorrer alguma mudança no banco, envie uma notificação para o usuario. Algúem saberia me dizer se é possivel, e se sim , como??

Comment: Qual a plataforma que você quer utilizar, pois você pode usar os pseudo Treads do python.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a extensão '.pyw' para não abrir o terminal. Colocar o programa em Loop e só abrir uma janela do Kivy quando a condição for verdadeira.